# Japanese song title vaguely translated to "Love song"

Tags: japan

This is a Japanese song I heard back in mid 2010s I believe the title was Koi no Uta (Love song) and it had a rap portion and the rest was kinda poppish. The only lyric I remember was that it vaguely had mentioned spaghetti. Sorry this is not a lot of information go to on with.

Comment: A quick google  search shows many songs called "Koi no Uta".  Can you give some more about what the song was part of or connected with ?  otherwise, it is going to be hard to ID this one

Comment: Hmm I don't recall if it was connected to anything I remember the opening lyrics "me wo tojite" close your eyes I believe